# KeyListener help Java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I've taken up learning Java. At the moment, I'm trying to get a key listener to work but I am struggling. My code is below. There is an error at the first curly bracket at the beginning of the anonymous inner class. I'm probably missing something simple, so any help would be useful.

```
public class Klistener extends JFrame {

    void Klistener()
    {
        JPanel c = new JPanel();
        c.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
        this.add(c);
        c.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {


            @Override
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
          {
              if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
              {
                  System.out.print("hi");
              }
          }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Klistener a = new Klistener();
        JFrame b = new JFrame("hi");
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setSize(500, 500);


        b.setLocation(500, 200);
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"there is a error at the first curly bracket ... I'm probably missing something simple"*  Yes.  That thing would be a stack trace or compilation error.  That and that we are not looking at your monitor, or psychic.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to provide implementations for the [other two methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) of `KeyListener`. If you don't want to do that, extend [`KeyAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) instead of `KeyListener`. `KeyAdapter` provides empty implementations of all of `KeyListener`'s methods so you can pick and choose which ones to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Since `KeyListener` is an `interface`, your inner class needs to override all the methods that have been declared in the interface. The interface specifies the following methods:

```
public interface KeyListener extends EventListener {

    /**
     * Invoked when a key has been typed.
     * See the class description for {@link KeyEvent} for a definition of 
     * a key typed event.
     */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e);

    /**
     * Invoked when a key has been pressed. 
     * See the class description for {@link KeyEvent} for a definition of 
     * a key pressed event.
     */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e);

    /**
     * Invoked when a key has been released.
     * See the class description for {@link KeyEvent} for a definition of 
     * a key released event.
     */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e);
}
```

A better way is to use the [`KeyAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) `abstract` adapter class for receiving keyboard events. Over here, you can over-ride any specific `method` that you want and not all.

Also, since you're new to `Java` `Swing`, the following links might come in handy:

- [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)
- [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

And oh, I noticed that you've a method `void Klistener` in the class named `Klistener`. I'm assuming that you're trying to make a `constructor` and not a method per se. If this is the case, then realize that `constructors` do not have any return type! Here's [yet another link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) that might be of help.

Comment: `KeyListener` has three methods

Answer (score 2):

You have so many mistakes so I don't even know were to start:

1) `KeyListener` is an interface so you have to implement all method's.

2) Don't add `KeyListener` to panel, add it to your `JFrame`. You can do that by creating anonymus class or this way

```
public class Klistener extends JFrame implements KeyListener{}
```

3) Don't call `setSize()` method, call `pack()` and `setPreferredSize()` method's and after that `setVisible(true)`, and call them in the end of the code.

This is how your main method should look:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Klistener k = new Klistener();
    k.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    k.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    k.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
    k.pack();
    k.setVisible(true);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You got some mistakes there. Here is a working code (**Minimum changes**):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
public class Klistener extends JFrame {
public Klistener()
{
    JPanel c = new JPanel();
    c.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);       
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {


        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)                
                        System.out.println("hi");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

    });

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Klistener a = new Klistener();
    a.setSize(500, 500);
    a.setLocation(500, 200);
    a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    a.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Comment: Why setVisible() before everything else, and why setSize(); Everything else is very good.

Comment: Taken from the original code without thinking...ill edit (thanks)

Comment: Since you are making edits.  1) Don't extend frame, keep a reference to one. 2) add some components (e.g. `JTree`) to the frame and `pack()` rather than `setSize()` 3) call `setLoctionByPlatform(true)` rather than explicitly setting a position. 4) Use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` 5) Start/update the GUI on the EDT. 6) Key bindings..

Comment: Why? I've posted a direct fix for the code with minimum changes. Improving the code will just make understanding the difference harder.